# call listview OnPagePropertiesChanging function from another function in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, listview

I have an aspx ListView control, a data pager for paging, paging is working fine. Now I have a dropdown to change page size and show the relevant records in listview. But dropdown not working properly.

I have total 14 records and when i go to 2nd page which has 4 records after that i change dropdown page size to 30 then it does not reflect listview and still showing same 4 records. It changes page number from 2nd to 1st only.

**HTML:-**

```
<asp:DropDownList  ID="ddlCount" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" 
SelectedIndexChanged="ddlCount_SelectedIndexChanged">                 </asp:DropDownList>

         <asp:ListView ID="lvParkingLots" runat="server" GroupPlaceholderID="grp" ItemPlaceholderID="item"
                                                GroupItemCount="2" OnPagePropertiesChanging="lvPL_PagePropertiesChanging">
                                                <LayoutTemplate>
                                                    <table class="table table-striped tblForm" id="gs">
                                                        <tr id="grp" runat="server">
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr class="pagination-listview">
                                                            <td></td>
                                                            <td style="float: right;">
                                                                <asp:DataPager ID="dp" runat="server" PagedControlID="lvParkingLots" PageSize="30">
                                                                    <Fields>
                                                                        <asp:NumericPagerField NextPageText="Next" PreviousPageText="Prev" />
                                                                    </Fields>
                                                                </asp:DataPager>

                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </LayoutTemplate>
```

**C# function:-**

```
 protected void lvPL_PagePropertiesChanging(object sender, PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)
    {          
            DataPager dp = (lvParkingLots.FindControl("dp") as DataPager);            
            dp.SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, false);
            Binddata();            
    }
```

**I have tried below code but not working..**

```
 protected void ddlCount_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      Binddata(); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to the event is of type object, here it should be the ListView, and the second argument will be `PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs` which is expecting StartRowIndex and MaximumRow, both are of type integer, so you can call that method like this:

```
int startRowIndex =2,MaximumRow=3;
lvPL_PagePropertiesChanging(lvSample, new PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs(startRowIndex , MaximumRow));
// where lvSample is the listview
```

In the case of the second example, you have to call the method like this:

```
ddlCount_SelectedIndexChanged(ddlCount, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Comment: now its going to lvPL_PagePropertiesChanging function but not showing relevant data. listview has same data.

Comment: are you getting any errors or exceptions? hope that you have passed correct values for `e.StartRowIndex and e.MaximumRows`, could you please cross check what is happening inside the method through BKPS

Comment: no exceptions, how to get  data pager's start row index in  ddlCount_SelectedIndexChanged function?